# How can I use two different docker container on the production server (after pushing to DockerHub)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

I have the `docker-compose` file with two containers. "nginx" container depends on "demo" (it's python django backend).

```
version: '3.9'

volumes:
  static:

services:
  demo:
    image: findsimilar/demo
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 8080
    volumes:
      - static:/static/
    command: bash -c "
      python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --settings=demo.prod_settings
      && gunicorn demo.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8080
      "
  nginx:
    image: findsimilar/demo-nginx
    build: ./nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static:/etc/nginx/static/
    depends_on:
      - demo
```

I've done `docker compose build` and `docker compose push`.
Images have been pushed on DockerHub.

The question is "How can I properly use this images on production server?"
I've tried `docker run findsimilar/demo` and `docker run findesimilar/demo-nginx`.
The images have been pulled but `findsimilar/demo` haven't been started and `findsimilar/demo-nginx` didn't find a demo:8080 host.

Answer (score 0):

In the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml` one can do:

1. Start containers (detached mode): `docker-compose up -d`
2. Stop containers: `docker-compose down --remove-orphans`

Comment: Thanks. Containers run properly on local machine with `docker compose up`. And I if put all the project on the production server it runs too. But 

I don't really understand the role of DockerHub. Can I just push images in DockerHub and run this images on production or I need all the project structure in production server anyway?

Comment: @LevanLomidze can your production server access DockerHub? Are you using DockerHub and a private Docker registry?

Comment: yes my productions server have access to DockerHub. It is public DockerHub and public images.

Comment: If the production server can access DockerHub, it should be able to pull the versions of the Docker images, as needed, when running docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got the answer.

To use my DockerHub images on production I need special docker-compose file, without build detective. This is the work example in my case:

```
version: '3.9'

volumes:
  static:

services:
  demo:
    image: findsimilar/demo
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 8080
    volumes:
      - static:/static/
    command: bash -c "
      python manage.py collectstatic --noinput -- 
   settings=demo.prod_settings
  && gunicorn demo.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8080
  "
  nginx:
    image: findsimilar/demo-nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static:/etc/nginx/static/
    depends_on:
      - demo
```

The file is similar with docker-compose in the question but without `build` and `context`

I did `docker compose pull` and `docker compose up -d` on my server and it worked.